# In web automation(selenium+python) when running code without a headless working fine but with headless{chrome} it navigates to the unexpected page

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, headless

Using Python / seleniumm running without headless mode is working fine but with headless Chromedriver it navigates to an unexpected page.

Python code:

```
if value == "True":
    chromeOptions.add_argument("--headless")            
    chromeOptions.add_argument('window-size=1920,1080')         

capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()        
if self.getPlateform() == "Windows":
    chromedriver = self.SRC_DIR +'yxyz\\chromedriver.exe'
else:
    chromedriver = self.SRC_DIR +'yxyz/chromedriver'
    logging.info(chromedriver)
    return webdriver.Chrome(
        executable_path=chromedriver,
        options=chromeOptions, 
        desired_capabilities = capability
    )
```

Comment: Which unexpected page :/

Comment: After login I expected to user dashboard page but it navigate to profile page

Comment: Requests are sent too fast and session blocked by previously made. You can try to add network throttling to slowdown. Or you need wait all AJAX calls finished on page load, and then request next page. any idea on that @DebanjanB